# How to track or watch specific posts on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I found an interesting post on Twitter (in this format `twitter.com/<user>/status/<number>`). This post has hundreds of replies but I am interested only with comments to this post.

How to track or watch this post in real-time sorted by date of adding new comment?

Comment: Please note that requests for app recommendations are off-topic here. I've removed that part of your post, but since the rest of the question has a well-defined problem you're trying to solve, it's now okay.

Comment: You'd probably need a browser extension or app for that. Are you using Twitter in a web browser? Android? iOS?